# If $|A|=pq$ and $A\lhd B$ is a Nontrivial Normal Subgroup, the Quotient Group $A/B$ is Cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

I want to prove that $A/B$ is cyclic when $B$ is non-trivial normal subgroup of $A$, and $|A|$ = $pq$ such that $p$ and $q$ are primes.

I had the idea of using Lagrange's Theorem which states that 'the order of any subgroup of group $A$ is a divisor of the order of $A$', along with the idea that $A$ must contain an element '$a$' of order $q$; then prove that $A/B$ is cyclic since the '$a$' of order $q$ could be the left side generator of the set of (left) cosets of $B$ in $A$ (thus using the trivial normal subgroup $B$ to form a cyclic quotient group $A/B$)...

but I am coming up empty when trying to prove this directly...

Answer (score 5):

If $B$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $A$, then $|B| \in \{p,q,pq\}$. In any case, $|A/B| = |A|/|B| \in \{q,p,1\}$, and recall that, any group of prime order is cyclic.

Comment: Thank you!! would this hold true without loss of generality? (or more specifically would this work if |A| = 33?)

Comment: I don't think you're using the phrase "without loss of generality" correctly. Of course this would work in the specific case where $\lvert A \rvert = 33$, because then you could choose $p = 3$ and $q = 11$ and apply the result, which @Azif00 just proved for you.

Comment: @user1618033988749895 Well, yes. We do not require more properties the group.

Comment: thank you guys! I'm kinda a newbie to this abstract algebra stuff... and the learning curve of this as a hobby hasn't been to kind to me either haha